# Custom Permalinks and filters?

Tags: permalinks, filters

Ok, so I've added a custom permalink, which is mapping to my page fine. For some reaosn though the filters I've added aren't showing up. In the shortcode, they're just being returned as NULL.

My code is;

```
function custom_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {
$feed_rules = array(
    'local/(.*?)/(.*?)/?$'  =>  'index.php?page_id=41&trade=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&area=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2),
    'local/(.*?)/(.*?)?$'  =>  'index.php?page_id=41&trade=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&area=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2),
);
$wp_rewrite->rules = $feed_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}

function custom_wp_querystring() {
add_rewrite_tag('%trade%','([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_tag('%area%','([^&]+)');
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_wp_querystring');
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite' );

add_shortcode('rewrite_local', 'rewriteShortcode');

function rewriteShortcode() {
echo "vars are";
var_dump($wp_query->query_vars['trade']);
var_dump($wp_query->query_vars['area']);
}
```

Is it something simple I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the `custom_rewrite` function, try concatenating `$wp_rewrite->rules` and `$feed_rules` using [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), then returning `$wp_rewrite`.

```
function custom_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {
  $feed_rules = array(
    'local/(.*?)/(.*?)/?$'  =>  'index.php?page_id=41&trade=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&area=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2),
    'local/(.*?)/(.*?)?$'  =>  'index.php?page_id=41&trade=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&area=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2),
  );
  $wp_rewrite->rules = array_merge($feed_rules, $wp_rewrite->rules);
  return $wp_rewrite;
}
```

I haven't tested that at all, just a suggestion of something to be looking at.